# Using Twilio Verify API with Mailgun

Tags: python, django, authentication, twilio, mailgun

I'm using Twilio verify API to use OTP verification in my project. I have implemented SMS verification with Twilio. but for email Twilio is using Sendgrid and for some reason I can not use Sndgrid. I am already using Mailgun. So is there any way I can just send the Twilio Verify OTP Mail with mailgun.

here is my twilio verify function -

```
def verifications_email(email, via):
                msg = client.verify \
                        .services(settings.TWILIO_VERIFICATION_SID) \
                        .verifications \
                        .create(to=email, channel=via)

def verification_checks(email, token):
        return client.verify \
                    .services(settings.TWILIO_VERIFICATION_SID) \
                    .verification_checks \
                    .create(to=email, code=token)
```

so can anyone please give me a suggestion what should do to solve my problem? I don't even if it's even possible or not so maybe is there any other option that I can use. Thank You!

Comment: I am having the same issue. Pls share if you found a solution.